# discord.js sending message to specific channel

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js, channel

I've been looking around, can't quite seem to find the answer to this issue I am having with a discord bot I am making with Typescript. I have all of my commands in their own folder using a separate file for each command. Helps to keep things organised.

I've seen people say `` client.channels.get(`channelID`).send(`Text`) ``

but that's giving me 
`Object is possibly 'undefined'.` and `Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Channel'.`

I'm actually trying to make a bot message every text channel (given from a list) whenever someone runs a reboot command because for whatever reason people keep rebooting the bot. I implemented it as a funny thing to do every now and again as a troll if someone needs to use it. The bot goes offline for 3 minutes but I don't like having people spam it and pretty much have the bot un-usable.

I'm using `client.channels.get(channels.channelnames[5]).send("This is a message.")`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the content of `channels.channelnames[5]` definitely the channel ID and not the name?

Comment: I tried using both names and ids. Whatever I put in there it is given as a string variable.

Comment: I put in client.channels.get(channels.channelids[1]); and it doesn't return an error, but I can't send a message to it because it is registered as Discord.Channel and not Discord.TextChannel

Comment: TextChannel is a child of Channel and should be able to send messages if it's appropriate to do so. You should be able to echo out the [.type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type) property to check you're getting a text-like channel and not a voice one for example. The example in your question _should_ work so long as it's a text-like channel and the ID you're using is an actual channel id.

Comment: I got the channel id by right clicking on my text channel and hitting "Copy ID" It gave out "651560565080195122" which I assume is meant to be in the string format.

Comment: Something else, the issue is that the code doesn't want to compile as it sees "channel" as not a "textchannel" therefore when I added the ".send" command afterwards it returned an error. I get the feeling client.channels.get is returning a boolean value but I am not too experienced in discord.js as it would seem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
if(msgObject.member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === channels.channelnames[5]) as Discord.TextChannel) {
    var txtchannel = msgObject.member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === channels.channelnames[5]) as Discord.TextChannel
    txtchannel.send("This is a message in a channel. Don't know why you read this.")
}
```

so I was on the right track mostly. just had to do `as Discord.TextChannel` and I think that's why Cynthia was saying about casting the variable as a `TextChannel`

This code works. thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: Something I was looking since 2+ hours. Even the Discord JS  guide does not have this.. or maybe I missed.. anyway, thanks :p

Answer (score 1):

According to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection it seems like there is no get method.

Try `client.channels[channels.channelnames[5]].send("This is a message.")`

In other words try to replace .get with the square brackets.

EDIT: Sorry I was a bit quick, I think the issue is type casting, try casting the `Channel` to a `TextChannel` if you know that it is a text channel.

Comment: Problem : "Element implicity has an 'any' type because type 'Collection<string, Channel>' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get' ?"

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, I read it incorrectly I put in an edit, try that please.

Comment: My main issue is that I don't know how to convert a Discord.Channel to a Discord.TextChannel...

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming your channels are text ones.

```js
client.on('ready',(e)=>{


    let channel_ids = ['123','456','789'];

    // loop through the list of channel ids.
    for(let i=0, l=channel_ids.length; i<l; i++){
        let channel_id = channel_ids[i];

        let this_channel = client.channels.get( channel_id );

        // if exists, and type in list send message
        if(this_channel && ['dm', 'group', 'text'].indexOf( this_channel.type ) != -1){
            this_channel.send('a cool message')
            .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${message.content}`))
            .catch(console.error);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Errors (3): 
- Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7006) [24. 24]
- Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Channel'. ts(2339) [37,30]
- Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.