# How to send message to a specific channel with discord bot?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I have searched the internet and I haven't found a solution to send a simple message to a specific channel. All the answers that I found were outdated. What's the newest way of sending a message to a specific channel?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
const channel = <client>.channels.cache.get('<id>');
channel.send('<content>');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js sending message to specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273659/discord-js-sending-message-to-specific-channel)

Comment: the problem is that I use typescript, and it gives me an error but when compiled it works. is there anyway of getting rid of that error? `Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Channel'.ts`

Comment: I took a into the discord.js repo. The child classes of Channel do have a `send()` method, but not the Channel.ts itself. You could make that method abstract in there, what would fix that TypeScript error.

Comment: I put `public send(message: string)` in the Channel class constructor and the ts error disappeared, but is that good practice? is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: You should contribute that to the discord.js repository.

Answer (score 0):

a channel does not nessecairy have the send function like a voice channel. we have to check it actually is one, with the following code you should be able to:

```
const channel = <client>.channels.cache.get('<id>');
if(channel.isText()){
    channel.send('<content>');
}
```